# How do i pre load all the sounds that I need in a Pygame game, dynamically in a trie structure?

Tags: python-3.x, dictionary, audio, pygame, wav

Pygame cannot open files

I tried to open files 'with open as', with wave.open as' open single file without creating a dictionary. like `sound = Pygame.mixer.Sound('sounds/example.wav')` after the `Pygame.mixer.init()`

#### spy_vs_spy.py

```
import pygame
import settings
import game_functions as gf
import resources
import sounds
from spy_white import Spy_white
from spy_black import Spy_black
from settings import Settings


def run_game():

    # Initialize pygame, settings, and screen object.
    pygame.mixer.pre_init(frequency=44100, size=-16, channels=2, buffer=4096)
    pygame.init() #turn all of pygame on.
    pygame.mixer.init()
    print(pygame.mixer.get_init())
    ai_settings = Settings()
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(
            (ai_settings.screen_width, ai_settings.screen_height), 
            pygame.HWSURFACE|pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
    pygame.display.set_caption("Spy vs Spy 2019")
    resources.load_images(ai_settings, screen)
    resources.load_sounds()

    # Make Spy white.
    spy_white = Spy_white(ai_settings, screen)

    # Make Spy black.
    spy_black = Spy_black(ai_settings, screen)

    # Start music
    sounds.play_music()

    # Start the main loop for the game.
    while True:
        gf.check_events(spy_white, spy_black)
        spy_white.update()
        spy_black.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings, screen, spy_white, spy_black)

run_game()
```

#### resources.py

```
sound_library = {}

def load_sounds():

    global sound_library

    """Load all sounds from subdirectories in a dictionary"""
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('sounds'):
        for name in filenames:
            if name.endswith('.wav'):
                key = name[:-4]
                snd = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
                sound_library[key] = snd

    for sound in sound_library:
        print(sound)

    print(sound_library)
```

I intended to pre load all wav files as a sound in a dictionary, so I can call the sound by event just by giving the key in the sound library dictionary. and then execute `resources.sound_library['sound_to_play'].play()`

Traceback (most recent call last): File "/Users/ruudkooistra/Desktop/project_folder/spy_vs_spy_2019/spy_vs_spy.py", line 42, in  run_game() File "/Users/ruudkooistra/Desktop/project_folder/spy_vs_spy_2019/spy_vs_spy.py", line 24, in run_game resources.load_sounds() File "/Users/ruudkooistra/Desktop/project_folder/spy_vs_spy_2019/resources.py", line 36, in load_sounds snd = pygame.mixer.Sound(os.path.join(dirpath, name)) pygame.error: Unable to open file 'sounds/spy_fly.wav' [Finished in 1.3s with exit code 1]
[cmd: ['/usr/local/bin/python3', '-u', '/Users/ruudkooistra/Desktop/project_folder/spy_vs_spy_2019/spy_vs_spy.py']] [dir: /Users/ruudkooistra/Desktop/project_folder/spy_vs_spy_2019] [path: /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/Users/ruudkooistra/anaconda3/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin]

when i change the code as below, the pygame.mixer.music.load(file) and .play() works but Pygame.mixer.Sound(file) still does not. By the way there are links to the file stored in dictionary when I do it this way and I want to store the data dynamically in the heap in a trie structure. But I am a newbie and maybe there are better ways to handle sounds in a game with Pygame. It works fine with images.

def load_sounds():

```
global sound_library

"""Load all sounds from subdirectories in a dictionary"""
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('sounds'):
    for name in filenames:
        if name.endswith('.wav'):
            key = name[:-4]
            snd = os.path.join(dirpath, name)
            sound_library[key] = snd

for sound in sound_library:
    print(sound)

print(sound_library)
```

spy_fly
electrified
time_bomb_countdown
wave_stick
search_01
time_bomb_explode
beat
timer_01
pistol_trap_set
pistol_trapped
hit
bomb_explode
walking
spy_vs_spy_theme
found_item
trap_set
lift_off
door
spy_angel
{'spy_fly': 'sounds/spy_fly.wav', 'electrified': 'sounds/electrified.wav', 'time_bomb_countdown': 'sounds/time_bomb_countdown.wav', 'wave_stick': 'sounds/wave_stick.wav', 'search_01': 'sounds/search_01.wav', 'time_bomb_explode': 'sounds/time_bomb_explode.wav', 'beat': 'sounds/beat.wav', 'timer_01': 'sounds/timer_01.wav', 'pistol_trap_set': 'sounds/pistol_trap_set.wav', 'pistol_trapped': 'sounds/pistol_trapped.wav', 'hit': 'sounds/hit.wav', 'bomb_explode': 'sounds/bomb_explode.wav', 'walking': 'sounds/walking.wav', 'spy_vs_spy_theme': 'sounds/spy_vs_spy_theme.wav', 'found_item': 'sounds/found_item.wav', 'trap_set': 'sounds/trap_set.wav', 'lift_off': 'sounds/lift_off.wav', 'door': 'sounds/door.wav', 'spy_angel': 'sounds/spy_angel.wav'}

Comment: Could you add the traceback of the error you got?

Comment: Better to add them in the question, they will be more readable. Click [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56321553/edit) and modify your question.

Comment: Have you tried using the absolute path? `os.path.abspath`

Comment: I tried that yesterday but it only gives me the whole path to that file, if I print out the dictionary then I see that all the path's are stored and not the data itself as a value. The keys are fine and Pygame.mixer.music.load().play(-1) can read those files but it still reads from harddrive this way and Pygame.mixer.Sounds().play still cannot open file's. I added the os.path.join to prevent this game to crash on a windows system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes I found da way, now everything works as it should and I can use pygame.mixer.Sound().play() or pygame.mixer.music.load().play() wherever I want:

***resources.py***
import os
import pygame as pg

sound_library = {}

def load_sounds():

```
global sound_library

"""Load all sounds from subdirectories in a dictionary"""
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('sounds'):
    for name in filenames:
        if name.endswith('.wav'):
            key = name[:-4]
            with open(os.path.join(dirpath, name), "rb") as file:
                buffer = file.read()  
                sound_library[key] = buffer

for sound in sound_library:
    print(sound)
```